# Как сюда добавить переменные?

Tags: python-3.x

Как мне в эту строку добавить переменные? Заместь "что ищем" и "страна" должны быть переменные.

```
data = list(c.search("8080: что ищем location.country: страна", IPV4_FIELDS, max_records=1000))
```

Comment: `f"8080: {переменная} location..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
looking = "что ищем"
country = "страна"

data = list(c.search(
    f"8080: {looking} location.country: {country}", 
    IPV4_FIELDS, max_records=1000
    )
)
```

Comment: Ошибка 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = list(c.search(f"8080: {looking} location.country: {country}", IPV4_FIELDS, max_records=1000))
NameError: name 'c' is not defined`

Comment: @NNEETT34 я не знаю что такое у вас `c`, но вам надо его определить.

Answer (score 1):

Форматирование строк:

```
data = list(c.search(f"8080: {foo} location.country: {bar}", IPV4_FIELDS, max_records=1000))

data = list(c.search("8080: {0} location.country: {1}".format(foo, bar), IPV4_FIELDS, max_records=1000))
```